# Bigquery Pricing - Copying Data between two tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I understand Copy and load operation is free in Big Query per -> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

I am trying to perform an ETL operation which requires copying weeks worth of data from Date partitioned table into a new temp table (ODS area) to perform some update operation. Once update is complete I need to truncate and re-load the data back to corresponding partitions in date partitioned target table. 
This operation moves large amount of data, I am trying to figure out if Big Query charges for selective copy (selecting only partition based on _partitiontime for bringing it to temp ODS and then copying the temp table back to the partition table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition decorators work when copying tables. Thus you can:

1. copy partition out (free) into separate table
2. do any manipulation with this table (cost of querying)
3. copy new table back to partition (free)